# Path, Curve, Contour in Complex Analysis

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, curves

"Let $[\alpha,\beta] (-\infty < \alpha\leq \beta)$ be a closed bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$.

A $\mathbf{curve}\, \gamma$ with parameter interval $[\alpha,\beta]$ is a continuous function $\gamma: [\alpha,\beta]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. It has initial point $\gamma(\alpha)$ and final point $\gamma(\beta)$ and is closed if $\gamma(\alpha) = \gamma(\beta)$. It is simple if $\alpha \leq s \leq t \leq \beta$ implies tbat $\gamma(s) \neq \gamma(t)$ unless $s=t$, or in the case of a closed curve, $s = \alpha$ and $t = \beta$."

This is the definition of a $\textbf{curve}$ in my textbook "Introduction to Complex Analysis" by H.A. Priestley.

I am just getting more and more confused on all I though I knew! Here are the things I don't get:

1. A curve is a continuous function. How can it be a function in the first place? There are examples in the book where I can take a line say $Re(z) = a$ in the Real axis, for some value $a$ and this will intersect the graph in more than one point!
2. It is parametrised. If it it parametrised, then how can it go back
   and forward, intersect and do all those "illegal" things? I thought
   that by parametrising it, I could use the values of $t$ from
   $\alpha$ to $\beta$ only once to sketch the graph! But if the curve
   crosses itself and goes ahead and behind, how can it be
   parametrised?

   3. The book then speaks about paths, and finally contours. And we want to integrate over contours, which are closed and formed by straight lines and arcs. We want to do so cause the integral along a closed contour is zero from what I could get. (not sure, it is quite vague) But then if $\mathbb{C}$ is a generalisation of $\mathbb{R}$ why doesn't this happen also in $\mathbb{R}$? I thought that only the integral of a conservative vector field along a closed path was equal to zero.

Comment: It is hard to parse your questions. A curve is a continuous function from some interval to the complex plane. I have no idea what you are talking about in 1. It is parameterised by some $t \in [a,b]$. For example, the circle can be written as the range of the curve $\gamma(t) = e^{it}$ on the interval $[0,2\pi]$. You can sketch the range of the entire curve using the values $\gamma(t)$ for $t \in [0, 2 \pi]$. You could also describe the circle using $\gamma(t) = e^{i2t}$ on the interval $[0,2\pi]$, in which case it runs over the circle twice.

Comment: But I thought that if I drew a vertical line on the graph of the function, it should intersect the graph only once? A function can't take one $x$ and output more than one $y$, can it?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are graphing this, but yes, that is correct, but you need to have some sort of 3d plotting to graph the curve $[a,b] \to \mathbb{C}$. Each point $\gamma(t)$ lies in the complex plane. I think you are confusing a graph from the line to the line (which can be represented in a plane) with the graph of a curve (which needs 3 dimensions to represent).

Comment: Oh wait maybe I got it! Please tell me if this is correct: the function would take two inputs ($Re(z),Im(z)$) and give one output ($z = Re(z)+iIm(z)$), so the graph would have $3$ dimensions (input1, input2, output). The curve is not the same thing as the graph and it is 2D and takes one input (the parameter) and give one output (the value of the function) ? Then why are we using the curve and not the graph??

Comment: No, the function takes a single real input, say $t$, and produces a single complex number. For example, a short straight line segment at 45 degrees to the real axis would be $\gamma(t) = t+it$ for $t\in [0,1]$. Think of describing the position of an ant over a time interval $[0,1]$ say. The position can be described as some function $a(t) = x(t)+i y(t)$. Clearly the ant can walk back over its tracks, but at different times.

Comment: So is it not very similar to a parametrised vector field with only two dimensions in Vector Calculus? For example when we evaluate the line integral of the vector field, we take $\underline{F}(\underline{r}(t))$ and if this has zero component in the direction of one of the standard basis vector, then it looks similar it, or is it totally different?

Comment: Whoa, you've gone way off piste there. I'm not sure what you are referring to by a parameterised vector field in this context.

Comment: What makes confusion to me is that most times we consider $i$ as just like $i^2 = 1$. However sometimes (like above!) we treat it as if $i$ was some kind of unit vector in the direction of the Imaginary axis.

Comment: Well, it is in some sense. We identify the point $(1,0)$ with $1$ and $(0,1)$ with $i$. However (and this is the big difference between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{C}$), the complex numbers have one dimension unlike $\mathbb{R}^2$ which has two.

Comment: So then, when we consider the point $a(t_0) = x(t_0) + iy(t_0)$, we are not really considering a point in the complex plane, but we are considering a position vector? Normally in the real plane there is a difference between the position vector and the point itself

Comment: The point $x+iy$ **is** in the complex plane. I'm not sure how to answer your last question in the previous comment. Just think of points in the current context. If you must think of a vector, think of the line that joins the origin to the point, or think of a vector as a displacement without a fixed initial point. However, I think reaching for this distinction adds unnecessary confusion here. I think you are over thinking this.

Comment: Okay so can you expand what you were saying in the first and second comment? I am not sure I understand why you said that we are considering it "line to line" and not 3d. Like it looks to me a function that takes one input and gives one output, so the representation on the plane, should be the graph. And the graph shouldn't cross itself or have multiple $y$ values for $x$.

Comment: A function $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$ takes a point in $[0,1]$ and returns a value in $\mathbb{C}$. So one representation of this is as a subset of $[0,1] \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, that is a giant slab infinite in two dimensions. So, essentially a 3d object not 2d.

Comment: So say I have $f: [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \,\, t\longmapsto 2t + i3t$ . Now if I take a point $t$ in $[0,1]$, say I take $t = 0.5$, then I have $0.5\longmapsto 1 + i1.5$, which is in $\mathbb{C}$. Now basically to represent it, I put $t$ (the input, in this case an example is 0.5) in one axis, the real part in another one (1) and then the imaginary part in another axis (1.5) and so I have a 3D graph? Is this correct?

Comment: Well, yes, that is one way to think of it. Just like we think of real to real functions as a certain kind subset of the plane, we can think of the curves as a subset of 3d. However, usually people forget about the parameterisation and talk about the range (such as the circle above), and this can be confusing.

Comment: I kind of understand a bit more now. So when we see a curve in a 2d plane, are we actually looking at the projection of the graph on the Complex Plane right? So when we see two lines crossing in 2d in a point, this point represents two points in 3d which have the same complex components, but different input component and hence they are at a different "height" and they do not cross? If this is the case, then how do we justify when the curve goes back and forth?

Comment: Think of the ant track. The parameter here is time, so if we really want to visualise the path we need to have a plane for each point in time and so will have a three dimensional object. However, we usually just think of the track and forget about the time, so we think of the ant track as the projection onto the plane and forget about the time factor. But if we want to know when the ant was at a specific place (and there may be many times for which this is true), we need to know the time parameterisation.

Comment: However, I think many authors in complex analysis are a little loose when dealing with curves, and this leads to subsequent confusion and delay.

Comment: Okay it makes kind of sense, thank you!

Comment: if you can make it into an answer I'll mark it as complete